# PushNotification setSound is not working properly for android os 8

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am using react native firebase library for push notification and i am playing two different sound for two different notification so i am playing some .mp3 sound for one notification and default for other one so problem is app is playing only that sound which is coming in first notification for app and for rest notification playing the first played sound so I think the issue is notification information is not updating that's what it is playing the same sound for all the notification which app got for first notification.even we are getting right information in notification data but it is not updating the sound.

Version:
react-native-firebase:"4.3.8"
react-native:"0.56.1"

yes I am getting data from firebase and below is my code to set Sound for notification.

```
this.notificationListener = firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotification((notification: Notification) => {

    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      'test-channel',
      'Test Channel',
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
    ).setDescription('My apps test channel');

    if (notification && notification.data) {
      const data = notification.data;
      if (data && data.messageKey) {
        //here I set the sound on basis of notification data to the channel

    ...
      } 
    }

    // Create the channel
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
    // Process your notification as required
    notification
    .android.setChannelId('test-channel')
    .android.setSmallIcon(Images.logoSmall);


firebase.notifications()
    .displayNotification(notification);
  });
```

Comment: Could you please post your code ? And also while debugging,  do you receive the data from firebase ?

Answer (score 1):

1) In android, add your custom sound file to [project_root]/android/app/src/main/res/raw  [image: here]

2) Create notification channel

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('channel_name', 'channel_name', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.High)
  .setDescription('channel_name')
```

3) Add sound into notification  .setSound('default')

```
firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
  sound: 'default',
  show_in_foreground: true,
})
  .setNotificationId(new Date().valueOf().toString())
  .setTitle(noti_payload.title)
  .setSound('default')
  .setBody(noti_payload.message)
  .setData({
    now: new Date().toISOString(),
    payload: noti_payload,
  })
  .android.setAutoCancel(true)
  .android.setBigText(noti_payload.message)
  .android.setLargeIcon('ic_launchers')
  .android.setVibrate(1000)
  .android.setColor('#74c900')
  .android.setColorized(true)
  .android.setChannelId('channel_name') // e.g. the id you chose above
  .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launchers') // create this icon in Android Studio
  .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

firebase
  .notifications()
  .displayNotification(localNotification)
```

**Important Note:-**

After doing above step please uninstall app and delete bundles, because some time cached bundle asset contain default sound and changes are not reflected.

every time you change sound you need to build bundle again

Please check following link also
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/notifications/reference/Notification

Comment: But you didn't mention the mp3 filename anywhere.

Comment: There is not need to mentioning sound name here because if you put sound in your raw folder it will worked with default name **setSound('default')**

Comment: What if we have multiple .mp3 file in same res/raw folder?

Comment: I was not try with multiple sound. if i am found solve i will let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

[`setSound()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes)) was deprecated in API 26. Use [`NotificationChannel.setSound()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes)) instead.

Comment: I used used that NotificationChannel.setSound() for API 26 so the problem is notification is playing only one sound even if we set different sounds.If your first notification for app has sound like "alert.mp3" so it will play that sound for the all other notification even if you set "default" for others.